# Can't find 'Web Content' in Control Panel (Beginner)

Tags: liferay

newbie to Liferay here. I'm trying to follow the documentation from [here](https://dev.liferay.com/discover/portal/-/knowledge_base/6-1/advanced-content-with-structures-and-templates#editing-a-structure). The first line says:

> *Go back to the Control Panel and select Web Content from the content section.*

However, when I go to the control panel of my Liferay site, I do not see any content section or a "Web Content" category. Here is a screenshot of what my control panel looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzMTF.png

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should start with the section _Web Content Management_, before you read _Advanced Web Content Management_.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. From the Control Panel, You have to click on "Manage Liferay" on the bottom, and the content section can be seen on the sidebar on the left.

Comment: You can simply go through top bar > Admin > Content

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the document you are referring is of `Liferay 6.1` (see selected value of dropdown positioned on left-top below navigation) and the version you are using is `Liferay 6.2`

You can select relevant documentation from changing dropdown to `Liferay 6.2`

While, you can navigate to "Web Content" section by clicking:

> Top-bar > Admin > Content